# How to use QStandardItemModel in PyQt5 to show data from a JSON file into a ListView?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a JSON file, I am able to fetch the data. Now, I want to display data into ListView using QStandardItemModel, but I am unable to understand how to implement. Can someone please suggest a basic implementation of how to display data so I have an idea?

Following is JSON file :

```
[
  {
    "due": "2019-12-09",  
    "project": {
      "id": 1, 
      "name": "Volcano"
    },  
    "Assignment_name": [
      {
        "id": 35, 
        "name": "Alex"
      }
    ], 
    "subject": null,    
  },
  {
    "due": "2019-10-19",  
    "project": {
      "id": 2, 
      "name": "Volcanic"
    },  
    "Assignment_name": [
      {
        "id": 36, 
        "name": "Alexa"
      }
    ], 
    "subject": null,    
  }
  ]
```

Comment: share your JSON

Comment: Surely you mean a tree-view, rather than a list-view, given that your data is hierarchical?

Comment: How do you want the information to be displayed?